# Рекурсивный вызов. Как узнать, какая функция выполняется в данный момент?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, рекурсия

Я взял алгоритм для перебора перестановок:

> Генерация всех перестановок Основная идея алгоритма генерации всех
>   перестановок заключается в следующем. В массиве длины n, содержащем
>   перестановку, будем менять последний элемент с каждым, после чего
>   будем рекурсивно будем делать то же самое для массива длины n-1 и
>   затем возвращать переставленный элемент на старое место. Если
>   достигнута длина массива n=1, то переставлять ничего не нужно, а
>   следует выдавать содержимое всего массива-перестановки на экран. Такой
>   алгоритм позволит сгенерировать все перестановки, что следует из
>   словесного рекурсивного определения: на последнем месте побывает
>   каждый элемент, содержащийся в рассматриваемом массиве, после чего к
>   оставшейся части массива рекурсивно будет применен тот же алгоритм.

Написал код, взятый также из примера. Все работает, но хочу разобраться, как именно. Сложно понять, какая именно запущена функция `Perm`, порядок их действия. Например, в выводе хочется что-то вроде:

запуск 1, Perm_id 1

запуск 2, Perm_id 2

запуск 3, Perm_id 1

№ запуска посчитать могу, просто счетчик добавить, а с "ид" функции не пойму...

Сам код перестановок:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int n = 4;
int arr[n] = { 1,2,3,4 };
int cnt = 0;    // счетчик

void swap(int *arr, int a, int b);
void printArr(int *arr);
void Perm(int *arr, int k);

int main() {
    Perm(arr, n);
    return 0;
}

void Perm(int *arr, int k) {
    if (k == 1) {
        printArr(arr);
        return;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
            swap(arr, i, k - 1);
            Perm(arr, k - 1);
            swap(arr, i, k - 1);
        }
    }
}
void swap(int *arr, int a, int b) {
    int s = arr[a];
    arr[a] = arr[b];
    arr[b] = s;
}

void printArr(int *arr) {
    cnt++;
    cout << cnt << ".\t";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Я не вижу вопроса. Вы хотите разобраться, как работает код. Что Вам мешает это сделать непонятно. Что подразумевается под `id` функции также не ясно.

Comment: Возможно, вам поможет одна из следующих ссылок: * https://prog-cpp.ru/permutation/ * https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8,_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%99%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%B0  * https://habrahabr.ru/post/248493/

Comment: Хочу, чтобы каждый запуск рекурсивной функции сопровождался сообщением: `я функция № 4.` Да, разобраться как рекурсия, можно и без этого. Но почему вопрос не имеет места быть? Вопрос же не в том, как работает данная функция, а в том, как вывести в консоль порядок выполнения рекурсии. Такой вывод упростит понимание, да и проверить неплохо бы, правильно понял код или нет...  Ну и спасибо вам за минус.

Comment: Что вы понимаете под номером функции?

Comment: функция запускает сама себя. Каждый новый ее запуск хочу идентифицировать, если это вообще возможно. То есть все, что именно этот конкретный запуск сделал вывести в консоль с уникальным номером этого запуска.

Comment: Я попытался дать ответ на Ваш вопрос. Можно пробовать выводить, в т.ч. указатель на функцию. Это в довесок к Вашему вопросу. Но всё равно, не до конца понятно, что Вы хотите, а самое главное зачем хотите получить этот уникальный идентификатор?

Answer (score 2):

По сути, вы хотите построить дерево рекурсии. Почему это именно дерево. Довольно очевидно. Давайте условимся, что у нас при каждом новом вызове функции создаётся новая функция (т.е. не может дёрнуться предыдущая или какая-то следующая, которая будет вызвана когда-нибудь потом). Т.е. мы вызываем функцию здесь и сейчас и вызвана в другом месте она быть не может. При этом, без потери общности, будем говорить, что все вызываемые функции будут одинаковыми, т.е. последовательность действий (а точнее правила выполнения действий) в них не отличается друг от друга. Проиллюстрируем

[image: Граф переходов между копиями функции][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIzY4.png)

Здесь синими стрелками показан выход из рекурсии. Красными -- заглубление по рекурсии. Если обратить внимание только на красные стрелки, то отчётливо проступит дерево. Этому можно дать строгое доказательство. Но думаю, что этого не требуется.

Теперь о том, как поступить в Вашем случае, чтобы понять, где в этом дереве мы находимся. Давайте всякий раз будем выводить на экран глубину рекурсии. В таком случае, мы сможем "примерно" понимать, где мы находимся. Если на каком-то этапе глубина рекурсии будет повторяться, то это означает, что мы зашли в другую ветку дерева рекурсии.